# Convert color space to graysacle

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing

I am learning about image processing now. I use Qt Creator as IDE and I want to convert color from YCrCb to Gray. I want to use cvtColor function but I can't find function CV_YCrCb2GRAY. There are only CV_RGB2GRAY and CV_BGR2GRAY function. So, how can I convert YCrCb color space to Gray color space?

Comment: Just throw away the Cb and Cr channels.

Comment: To add to squeamish ossifrage's comment. The Y component in YCbCr is the luminescence aka light intensity. This is exactly what a grayscale image displays.